# Padding a string in Objective-C/IOS like PHP's str_pad() function?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, ios6, nsstring

I want to be able to pad a string to the left up to a certain character length, in IOS. My strings are id numbers that vary in length:

```
1 
12 
356 
456089
```

I need them to look like this:

```
00000000001 
00000000012 
00000000356 
00000456089
```

In PHP I would use the str_pad() function:

```
$pad_Length = 11;
$padded_string = str_pad($input_string, $pad_Length, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

How is this done in iOS / Objective-C?

**Answer:**

```
NSString *input_string = @"123";
int pad_Length = 11;
NSString *padding = [@"" stringByPaddingToLength: pad_Length - [input_string length] 
                                      withString: @"0" 
                                 startingAtIndex: 0];
NSString *padded_string = [padding stringByAppendingString: input_string];
```

Comment: A program to implement padding would take 2-3 lines in any language. Practically one in case of only left padding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not tested this but

```
NSString* stringToPad = @"123";
NSString* padding = [@"" stringByPaddingToLength: 11 - [stringToPad length] 
                                      withString: @"0" 
                                 startingAtIndex: 0];
NSString* result = [padding stringByAppendingString: stringToPad];
```

The documentation [stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBBDAAF)

Comment: Just had to make sure to add a semicolon after the first line.

Comment: @kyzer1978 Good spot about the semicolon.  Fixing...

Answer (score 2):

hi you can try to tansfer NSString into Integer 
just like this:

```
NSArray *strs=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"123",@"9234",@"125",@"5123", nil];
    for (NSString *str in strs) {
        NSInteger i=[str integerValue];
        NSString *paddedStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%011d",i];
        NSLog(@"%011d",i);
    }
```